# Change date time on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS manually?

Tags: 16.04, azure

I need to change date time manually on the server Ubuntu 16.04, I disabled the ntp and disable the auto update the ntp from `timedatectl` using command:

```
timedatectl set-ntp 0
```

And following result is the `timedatectl` command :

```
Local time: Wed 2017-02-22 13:31:46 +0530
  Universal time: Wed 2017-02-22 08:01:46 UTC
        RTC time: Wed 2017-02-22 14:33:39
       Time zone: Asia/Colombo (+0530, +0530)
 Network time on: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

But when I change the time manually using `sudo date -s "22 FEB 2017 07:30:00"` its not updated.

Note: My server is hosted on Azure.

I confirmed this happened after system update.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42386596/2072269

Comment: @muru : that link no longer available, it returns Page Not Found

Comment: @Sadee I'll look for another link, but iirc it said that Azure didn't yet support setting the system time